# How to make a smooth transition or display a loader while loading a lot of locally stored static content in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native screen with ScrollView displaying countries with their phone country codes.

```
const CountryCodes = () => {

import countries from "../../utils/countries";

 return (
    <ScrollView>
      {countries.map((country) => {
        return renderItem(country);
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  );
 };
```

the countries.js file is just an array of country data (c. 200 objects), together with require statements for the related assets, like this:

```
const countries = [{
    letterCode: "ad",
    phoneCode: "376",
    name: "Andorra",
    flag: require("../assets/flags/ad.png"),
  }]
```

I am using the Stack Navigator from React Navigation. The problem that I have is that when I am navigating to the CountryCodes screen, the screen is freezing (while, I assume, all the static flag images are loading) and after ~1 second it properly displays the ScrollView with all the countries.

Is there a way to make the transition smoother? I tried displaying a loader while the countries are loading, but the screen just keeps freezing with no chance to display anything in the meantime.
This issue is the same when using FlatList.

Please see the GIF below for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue while loading a heavy component. this happen to me while loading a country list , multiple graph and other heavy components.

if you press on a navigation button then there is some delay while navigating to that screen or component. I have write a custom hook for this.

paste the following code in your **useIsReady.js**

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import React from 'react'

const useIsReady = (stack = true) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = React.useState(false)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeFocus = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      if (!isReady) setIsReady(true)
    })

    const unsubscribeTransitionEnd = stack
      ? // @ts-ignore
        navigation.addListener('transitionEnd', () => {
          if (!isReady) setIsReady(true)
        })
      : undefined

    return () => {
      unsubscribeFocus()
      unsubscribeTransitionEnd && unsubscribeTransitionEnd()
    }
  }, [])
  return isReady
}

export default useIsReady
```

here you can display a loading indicator on that component or screen  Like this.

```
import useIsReady from '../../hooks/useIsReady';

  const DashBoardScreen = ({navigation}) => { 
      const isReady = useIsReady()
  if(!isReady){
                return(
                    <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center",}} >
                        <ActivityIndicator  size={"large"} color="red" />
                    </View>
            )
        }

return  <YOUR_HEAVY_COMPONENT />
}
```

}

or you can use lazy loading for multiple heavy components.

Here is the example for lazy loading

```
import React, {memo, useMemo,Suspense, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView,StatusBar,ActivityIndicator, Text,View,StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { scale, verticalScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';
import { commonStyles,textStyles } from '../../styles';
import { colors, fonts } from '../../constants/theme';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import { hp, width, wp } from '../../constants/sacling';
import {sales_slider, recruiter_slider} from './sales_slider'
const BarChart  = React.lazy(() => import('./BarChart')) 
const PieChart = React.lazy(() => import('./PieChart'))
const HalfPieChart = React.lazy(() => import('./HalfPieChart'))


    const ItemView = memo(({item}) => {
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity 
                style={styles.ItemView}>
                <View style={{...styles.IconBgView, backgroundColor:item.bgColor}}>
                    {/* <AntDesign name={item.icon_name} size={scale(20)} color={"#fff"} /> */}
                    {item.icon}
                </View>
                <View style={{marginLeft:scale(5)}}>
                    <View style={{flexDirection:"row", justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
                        <Text style={styles.countText}>{item.count}</Text>
                        <View style={styles.ArrowPercentageRowView}>
                            <FontAwesome 
                                name={item.arrow_icon} 
                                color={item.arrow_icon_color} 
                                size={scale(8)}
                            />
                            <Text style={styles.ItemViewPercentage} >
                                {item.percentage}
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.ItemViewTitle} >{item.title}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    })

    const CardView = memo(({title, items}) => {
        return(
            <View style={styles.CardView}>
                <Text style={styles.CardViewTitle}>{title}</Text>
                <ScrollView 
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} 
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    horizontal={true} >
                    {
                        items.map((item, index) => {
                            return(
                                <ItemView  
                                    key={`${index}`} 
                                    item={item}
                                />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    })

    const LoadingView = () => {
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1,height:hp(20), justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center",}} >
                <ActivityIndicator  size={"large"} color={colors.dark_primary_color} />
            </View>
        )
    }

    const DashboardAnaylyticsScreen = ({navigation}) => {
        const data = [
            { quarter:"Companies", earnings: .3 },
            { quarter:"Contacts", earnings: .6 },
            { quarter:"Meetings", earnings: .4 },
            { quarter:"Opportunities", earnings: .5 },
            { quarter:"Job Orders", earnings: .13 },
            { quarter:"Candidates", earnings: .16 },
            { quarter:"Interviews", earnings: .14 },
            { quarter:"Placements", earnings: .19 },
        ];
        const user_sales_actvites = [
            { quarter:"General Notes", earnings: .3 },
            { quarter:"Live Connect", earnings: .6 },
            { quarter:"Recieeved Email", earnings: .4 },
            { quarter:"Send Mails", earnings: .5 },
            { quarter:"Job Orders", earnings: .13 },
            { quarter:"Candidates", earnings: .16 },
            { quarter:"Interviews", earnings: .14 },
            { quarter:"Placements", earnings: .19 },
        ];
        const colors = ["tomato", "orange", "gold", "cyan", "navy", "pink", "gray","red" ]
        const RenderPieChart = useMemo(() => {
            return(
                <>
                    <Suspense fallback={<LoadingView />} >
                        <BarChart data={data} title={"General"} />
                    </Suspense>
                    <Suspense fallback={<LoadingView />} >
                        <PieChart data={data} colors={colors} />
                    </Suspense>
                    <Suspense fallback={<LoadingView />} >
                        <HalfPieChart data={data}  colors={colors} tilte={"Recruiter Performance"}/>
                    </Suspense>
                    {/* <Suspense fallback={<LoadingView />} >
                        <BarChart data={data} title={"Candidates in Stage"} />
                    </Suspense>
                     <Suspense fallback={<LoadingView />} >
                        <HalfPieChart data={data}  colors={colors} title={"Sales Performance"} />
                    </Suspense>
                  <Suspense fallback={<LoadingView />} >
                        <BarChart data={data} title={"Sales Activities"} />
                    </Suspense>
                      <Suspense fallback={<LoadingView />} >
                        <BarChart data={data} title={"Users Activities"} />
                    </Suspense> */}
                    {/*<Suspense fallback={<LoadingView />} >
                        <BarChart data={user_sales_actvites} title={"Sales Users Activities"} />
                    </Suspense> */}

                </>
            )
        },[data, colors])
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:colors.dark_primary_color}} >
                <StatusBar barStyle={"light-content"} />
                <View style={commonStyles.container} >
                    <ScrollView 
                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} 
                        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                        style={styles.container}>
                        <CardView 
                            title={sales_slider.title}
                            items={sales_slider.items}  
                        />
                         <CardView 
                            title={recruiter_slider.title}
                            items={recruiter_slider.items}  
                        />
                       {RenderPieChart}
                        <View style={{height:scale(100)}} />
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
            
        );
    };
    const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
       
          return true
      }
export default memo(DashboardAnaylyticsScreen,areEqual);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        width:width,
        backgroundColor:"#fff", 
        alignSelf:"center"
    },
    CardView:{
        width:wp(98),
        alignSelf:"center", 
        marginTop:scale(5), 
        borderWidth:1,   
        overflow:"hidden",
        borderRadius:scale(5),
        borderColor:"rgba(0,0,0,.1)"
    },
    CardViewTitle:{
        ...textStyles.Label,
        color:colors.text_primary_color,
        includeFontPadding:false,
        borderBottomWidth:1,
        fontFamily:fonts.Bold,
        borderColor:"rgba(0,0,0,.1)",
        padding:scale(5),
        width:wp(98)-2
    },
    ItemView:{
        flexDirection:"row",
        elevation:5,
       
        paddingHorizontal:scale(8),
        borderRadius:scale(5),
        borderRightColor:"rgba(0,0,0,.1)",
        alignItems:"center", 
        margin:scale(5), 
        backgroundColor:"#fff", 
        height:scale(40)
    },
    IconBgView:{
        width:scale(30),
        height:scale(30),
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center", 
        backgroundColor:"#1C264A",  
        borderRadius:scale(25)
    },
    countText:{
        ...textStyles.Label,
        fontFamily:fonts.Bold,
        color:colors.text_primary_color,
        includeFontPadding:false,
        fontSize:scale(10),
    },
    ItemViewTitle:{
        ...textStyles.Label,
        color:colors.text_primary_color,
        includeFontPadding:false,
        fontSize:scale(10)
    },
    ItemViewPercentage:{
        ...textStyles.Label,
        color:colors.text_primary_color,
        includeFontPadding:false,
        marginLeft:scale(2),
        fontSize:scale(8)
    },
    ArrowPercentageRowView:{
        flexDirection:"row",
        flex:1,
        alignItems:"center", 
        marginLeft:scale(10), 
        justifyContent:"flex-start"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

React native `ScrollView` doesn't do very well with a large number of entries. The recommendation is to use a `Flatlist` as it only renders the components that are currently visible in the viewport.You can see the usage [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist). If you need even faster performance, there's [FlashList](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/) by shopify which is blazing fast.

Example:

```
<FlatList
    data={countries}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.letterCode}
/>
```

You might need to change your `renderItem` to match the FlatList's renderItem signature.

Comment: Two things: 1) if I use FlatList, it does not improve the performance as rendering does not seem to be a bottleneck, but the stage of importing all the static assets (it takes roughly the same time to load the component using FlatList and ScrollView); 2) FlatList is not preferred here, since it is lazy loading the children, making it impossible to quickly scroll down to the bottom of the list, which is often the case with a list of alphabetically ordered countries.

Comment: Understood now. Yeah it's a predicament if you're using inline requires. I know this is not a solution, but can I suggest using remotely hosted assets. I'm currently using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-country-flag in a project and it's quite promising.

Answer (score -1):

This lead me to a lot of frustration, but I managed to work out a sort of a hack to accomplish the goal with the use of setTimeout, like this:

```
onPress={() => {
  setLoading(true);
  setTimeout(() => {
    navigation.navigate("Select Country")
  }, 0);
}}
```

When wrapped like this, the setLoading is executed first (and a lading screen appears) and only after after that the navigation.navigate is called and the Select Country screen appears after all the data is loaded.

Comment: this is not a good practice.